# I don't want spaces when I tab in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tabs, spaces

Whenever I add a tab in VS 2010, it puts spaces instead. I know you could fix this problem by going in the VS 2008 options, but I can't figure out how to fix this in VS 2010.

Comment: I think you have reasons to want this. But there are reasons to use spaces instead.
http://blog.nuclex-games.com/2013/02/why-you-should-indent-with-spaces/

Comment: @EdgarT, do you have an updated link? The above one doesn't work. Thanks

Answer (score 82, accepted):

```
Tools > Options > Text Editor > All Languages > Tabs > enable "Keep Tabs".
```

You can also adjust this setting on a per-language basis.

Comment: thx. I just realized that I had to click on the "show all settings" check box... noob error... but thanks

Comment: Same in VS 2013 BTW :)

Comment: Same in VS 2015 Update 2 + Python Tools March 2016 =)

Comment: Same in VS 2017 BTW

Comment: Same in VS 2019 BTW ;)

Answer (score -4):

Regarding the first anwser ...
"Keep Tabs" will only work until you start using linq queries.
When visual studio formats linq queries adds some spaces for paddind.

**There are no built-in support in vs2010 for strict indentation using tabs.**